# Conditional Formatting not being applied to sheet when data is added from another

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, microsoft

I have a training spreadsheet with conditional formatting showing dates passed, coming or in date for personnel.
When doing a data dump from the updated registry the sheet does not apply the conditional formatting unless I manually retype the date?
Can you please assist?
I have a snapshot of the sheet to show if there is a way to upload it here?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! When you edit your question, in the toolbar at the top there is an option to insert images by uploading them and then getting a link.

Comment: Depending on how you're pasting the data in you're probably also bringing over the original formatting and overwriting your conditional formats. Try right-clicking and doing Paste as Values

Comment: Could you provide a sample here?